# Flutter webview errors page not avaliable

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I developed an application in Flutter, I used the flutter_inappwebview package in it, but when I press the use the application button on the map, this page greets me. What is the solution?[image]

As a solution, I made sure of all permissions and my expectation is that it will be resolved only

Comment: what is your need? i mean your URL redirects to google maps view. can you explain?

Comment: i think your url is not correct

Comment: @JeelBhatti 
When I enter the map, there is a button that says switch to the map application, when I press it, I get this error

Comment: @AhmetEkremHafız can you profile web view code? need url..